# Database Access Time - Dependant on language?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

If I am going to use a SQLite database to store my data, I was wondering if the language of my program which requests the data will have any outcome on the access time.

For example, if I have my 100mb SQL database and I need to search if for a certain value, would I get faster results if I wrote my program in C as opposed to PHP to query and return the result from SQL?

I’m guessing the language doesn’t make a lot of difference since it is SQLite that is doing most of the heavy work, but I might be wrong.

Comment: It's probably more important to have useful indexes on you database.

Comment: yes you are right. SQL(ite) does 99.999% of the work. So the language doesn't really matter.